# I Cannot set background image in ionic 4 div from template

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-view

I am building a mobile app with ionic and I am trying to change the background image of the div but its not working

Here is the code

```
<div style="background-image: url(./assets/IMG/set3.jpg);">
......
</div>
```

I also changed the file path to

```
style="background-image: url(assets/IMG/set3.jpg);"

style="background-image: url(./assets/IMG/set3.jpg);"

style="background-image: url(/assets/IMG/set3.jpg);"
```

And I have other div of such, but the background image is not displaying, pls I need your help, I have search online but non of the solutions worked

Comment: Open the console and see what errors appear. If 404 appears, referring to images then it is an error in the address, if no error appears it is another problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to set background image to the entire page, you could use `--background` for `ion-content`. Something like following has worked for me.

```
ion-content {
--background: url('../../assets/BackgroundImages/splash-screen-background.png');
background-position: center center;
background-size:contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#css-custom-properties) are more details about `--background` CSS property

Comment: I want to set background image for the div not the ion-content

Answer (score 0):

Some IDEs (Visual Studio Code) allow you to ctrl click the url (follow link) and ensure that the resource is correctly pointed to. You may want to double check. Even otherwise please check if your assets folder is present at the same level as your page html. If it is not you may have to ensure the correct path, for ex.

```
background-image: url('../../assets/BackgroundImages/splash-screen-background.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the `background-image` directly with a style tag inside your `<div>`, give it a class. Then, inside your CSS, define the `background-image` on that class. That way, the IMG folder should be relative to the CSS file or the app-root. This always gets me with every new project, and it requires some trial and error to get it right.